# Can I use Stack Overflow for Q&A regarding my new framework?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am building a cloud based framework that allows programmers to develop and deploy business applications. I would like to use Stack Overflow to do some Q&A style posts on how to program it.

Would that be an acceptable use of Stack Overflow ?

I have checked the rules at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic but am still not sure.

Comment: Well, it depends on the questions you intend on asking...

Comment: You might get into the risk it's identified as _spamming_, unless your framework is already popular, and widely used.

Comment: This has likely been asked before -- search meta to find the duplicate.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Please read [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Then read https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

The short version of both is: you can answer questions about your product here, but they gotta be programming questions, you have to actually answer them here, and trying to "astroturf" - posting fake questions about your product - is gonna get you into hot water fast. If folks using your product want to ask about it here, great! If not, don't force it.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider hosting your own SO clone, if your userbase is compatible, meaning it's big enough for experienced users to answer questions for inexperienced ones.

I could have sworn I saw a hosted version of the SO software used by a company to support their product, but it doesn't look like SO itself is open-source (or available otherwise except for very large internal applications). However, there are apparently a great number of clones listed over on SE meta: [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones)

Something to look into if you think it'd be relevant to your needs.